# Change columns type if columns contain character in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have values in some column (non-null object) with character "%", for example

```
 col1     col2  col3 
'4.24%' '5.22%'  8
```

But I want 4.24 and 5.22 as a float.

```
I have tried with:
for el in df.columns:
    if df[el].str.contains('%').any():
        df[el] = df[el].str.strip("%").astype(float)
```

And said : `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

if I use:

```
if df['col1'].str.contains('%').any():
            df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.strip("%").astype(float)
```

then works fine. But with iteration through all column doesn't work.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert to strings before `str.contains('%')`, because it also test non string columns:

```
for el in df.columns:
    if df[el].astype(str).str.contains('%').any():
        df[el] = df[el].str.strip("%").astype(float) 

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0  4.24  5.22     8
```

Another better solution is use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for select only `object` columns (obviously `string`s):

```
for el in df.select_dtypes(object).columns:
    if df[el].str.contains('%').any():
        df[el] = df[el].str.strip("%").astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a column contains `'%'` it *must* be of `object` dtype. So you can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) first, apply your criteria, remove `'%'`, then use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

A Python-level loop is unavoidable to work on each series: you can use either a `for` loop or [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Here's a demonstration with `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['4.24%', '3.65%'],
                   'col2': ['5.22%', '3.56%'],
                   'col3': [8, 9]})

criteria = df.select_dtypes([object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('%').any())
cols = criteria[criteria].index

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('%'))\
                   .apply(pd.to_numeric)

print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0  4.24  5.22     8
1  3.65  3.56     9
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. :)